# How to delete the sheet 1 and sheet 2 with password protected

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with 20 worksheets. sheet1 and sheet 2 are both passwords protected. I want to create the new workbook by deleting sheet 1 and sheet 2 only using the VBA codes shown below but failing.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
     ws.UsedRange = ws.UsedRange.Value
    Next ws
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets(Array(1, 2)).Delete
End Sub
```

Please help to find out the problem

Comment: Copy only sheets from 3 to 20.

Comment: Your code can delete protected worksheets. However, it will raise run-time error 1004 if your workbook is protected.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. so how is the code to avoid make my VBA code work as sheet 1 and sheet 2 have to be protected in some areas to avoid some rows from being changed during editing...please help.